# add user control to a form

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have created a user control with a TextBox and two Buttons, but I haven't created events, just I place them to user control. When I want to add the user control to my form it says:

> Cannot move Task_control.cs. The destination folder is the same as the source folder.

I can't understand why.

Comment: In Custom control you will specify event.

Comment: How are you trying to add the user control to the form? Are you dragging it from **Solution Explorer** to the form?!

Comment: Yes. I drag it because it doesn't appear in toolbox.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

After creating your user control, you should build the project (<kbd>F6</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>).

Then Visual Studio automatically adds the control to the **Toolbox**. You should drag the control from the **Toolbox** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>) to the form.

If after successfully building the project, the control is not on the Toolbox, make sure that you have **Automatically Populate Toolbox** set to true: Go to **Tools->Options**, select **Windows Forms Designer** node, and set **Automatically Populate Toolbox** to **true**.

---

You can also manually add your user control to the toolbox (if "Automatically Populate Toolbox" is not set, and you don't want to set it!). It is highly recommended that you create an additional **Tab** on the Toolbox for your specific user controls: Right click on an empty area of the Toolbox and click **Add Tab**, then give the new tab a name.

Now build the project, right click on an empty area on the toolbox (of course, in tab you already created, or in the "General" tab), and select **Choose Items**:

[image: Adding controls to the Toolbox]

Wait a few seconds (or minutes) for the dialog to be ready, then click **Browse** and select your assembly. All of your user controls are now in the list. Select the ones you want to add to the Toolbox and click OK.

Answer (score 0):

After creating your user control, you should build the project from the Solution Explorer. Click on your project name and click build, If it doesn't work rebuild it again [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYFs3.png)