# Can't access dropdown selected index changed event?

Tags: c#, user-controls, selecteditem

I created a custom user control (see link: [Custom User Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21003072/how-to-access-selected-index-change-on-dropdown)

I "dropped" that user control into another Form, place a break point in the dropdown's selected index change event method, run the application and change the dropdown's value, it does hit my breakpoint. Why?

Comment: where do you exactly put your breakpoint? in your user control class?

Comment: Thanks Feri for your response. My colleague just assisted me. I made a change to the base control class and rebuild it. However, the base class's dll was being locked by another application so it wasn't being over written. Hence, my application was using an old dll.