# Usercontrol data gridview not loading with data

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, user-controls

I am creating a custom usercontrol with a `DataGridView` and I am adding this usercontrol to my form. In the `Form1_Load` event I am initialising the user control by invoking the constructor of the user control. Its  a parameterized constructor which has a `List` as argument and the list is being used as the `DataSource` for the `DataGridView` in the user control.

The problem is: the `DataGridView` is not loaded with the data.

can any one figure it out.

the code in the form load event is,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace usercontrol
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
         public Form1()
         {
            InitializeComponent();
         }

         private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();
             cars.Add(new Car("Ford", "Mustang", "1967"));
             cars.Add(new Car("Shelby AC", "Cobra", "1965"));
             cars.Add(new Car("Chevrolet", "Corvette Sting Ray", "1965"));                 

             ucSample uc = new ucSample(cars);
         }            
    }

    public class Car
    {
        private string company;
        private string color;
        private string year;
        public Car(string com,string col,string yea)
        {
            this.Company = com;
            this.Color = col;
            this.Year = yea;
        }

        public string Company { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public string Year { get; set; }   
    }       
}
```

The code in the user control is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace usercontrol
{
    public partial class ucSample : UserControl
    {
        public ucSample()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public ucSample(List<Car> listString)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataSource = listString;
        }

        public object DataSource
        {
            get { return dgvSample.DataSource; }
            set { dgvSample.DataSource = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the `DataGridView` have the property `AutoGenerateColumns` set to `true`?

Comment: yes I set it as true...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you create a custom control in an extra class but never add the control to your form to be displayed

A simple line will solve your problem:

```
this.Controls.Add(uc);
```

Put it in the constructor. That will ensure that your custom control is added to the `Form` for display

EDIT:

there is of course also a manual way: Here is an answer with screenshots [How do I add my new User Control to the Toolbox or a new Winform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471550/add-user-control-to-a-form)

Here is another one : [add user control to a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471550/add-user-control-to-a-form)

Comment: Thank you.   I thought while dragging from toolbox and droppng to the form, it will be added to the form.  So whenever I want to use a custom user control I have to use the same method or is there any other way to do this

Comment: @VipinJacob I put 2 links that show how to do it otherwise, check my edit

Answer (score 0):

datagridview is in user control.
that's why your Datagrid not loading with the user control in the Form.

1. Go to the userControl.cs
2. paste below code in the constructor

   "this.studentTableAdapter.Fill(this.universityDataSet.Student);"

In my case, the dataset is universityDataSet and the table is Student